# When I launch an asp.net application, IIS Express launches duplicates of running sites

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express

When I start my asp.net application in debug mode, IIS Express launches two instances of each endpoint. This does not allow the site to start fully.

How do I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

About the "duplicates"; If you look at the endpoints in your picture, you see that one is for `http` and one is for `https`. This is as expected.

I can also see that you are trying to open the https version (on port 44300) without specifying `https://`

Try opening http://localhost:8765 or https://localhost:44300

Comment: So also launched, does not work.
The main problem is that he will not open the site through IIS Express. He used to do it. Opening it simply through the IIS does not work, you just need to run it through the IIS Express.

Comment: No exceptions in debug mode?